# Purge file through ADF V2 before 60 days from ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I want to delete all the heavy files which are older than 60 days through my ADF pipeline but want to retain the files for the first 6 working days of the month (irrespective of the last 60 days).
Also, the files should be deleted on the name basis like Account, customer service, etc
My files are in ADLS V1.
Could you pl help me to get the approach here.I have gone through multiple blogs but cant find anything concrete.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only the Data Factory [Delete active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity) can help you delete all  files which are older than 60 days.

Delete the old files by the filter "Modified datetime":
[image]

But for now, Data Factory can not help you delete all the heavy files which are older than 60 days through my ADF pipeline but want to retain the files for the first 6 working days of the month.

Hope this helps.